# How to measure and compare performance for two different implementations?

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, xcode4, instruments

I have two different algorithms and want to know which one performs better in OpenGL ES.

There's this Time Profiler tool in Instruments which tells me how much % which line of code consumes of the overall processing time, but this is always relative to this algorithm.

How can I get an absolute value so I could compare which algorithm performs better? Actually I just need a percentage of overall CPU occupation. Couldn't find it in Time Profiler. Just percentages of consumed time but not overall CPU workload.

There was also a WWDC show talking about some nifty CPU tracker which showed each core separately. Which performance instrument do I need and at which values must I look for this comparison?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with either. Just current tick, run work aout elapsed and log, for both algorithms. Profiler is more use for evaluating an algorithm, than comparing two dfferent ones.

Comment: Both render at 60fps. What should I log there?

Comment: Huh? Something that measures the differences between the two algorithms. If the both go at 60 FPS, what would make you choose one over the other. Minimal memory, CPU, threads? If FPS is the characteristic you wanted, and they both meet it, then you could be being premature by picking one over the other before some other need has surfaced that drops the FPS in which ever one you are using. The other them might be a better choice, or not, either way you'll learn something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation you're talking about, optimizing OpenGL ES performance, is something that Time Profiler isn't well suited to help you with. Time Profiler simply measures CPU-side time spent in various functions and methods, not the actual load something places on the GPU when rendering. Also, the deferred nature of the iOS GPUs means that processing for draw calls can actually take place much later than you'd expect, causing certain functions to look like bottlenecks when they aren't. They just happen to be when actions queued up by earlier calls are finally executed.

As a suggestion, don't measure in frames per second, but instead report the time in milliseconds it takes from the start of your frame rendering to just after a `glFinish()` or `-presentRenderbuffer:` call. When you're profiling, you want to work directly with the time it takes to render, because it's easier to understand the impact you're having on that number than on its inverse, frames per second. Also, as you've found, iOS caps its display framerate at 60 FPS, but you can measure rendering times well below 16.7 ms to tell the difference between your two fast approaches.

In addition to time-based measurements, look at the Tiler and Renderer Utilization statistics in the OpenGL ES Driver instrument to see the load you are placing on the vertex and fragment processing portions of the GPU. When combined with the overall CPU load of your application while rendering, this can give a reasonable representation of the efficiency of one approach vs. another.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, the Time Profiler instrument has the CPU strategy, which lets you view each CPU core separately. Above the instrument list are three small buttons, where the center one is initially selected.

[image]

Click the left button to show the CPU strategy.

[image]